# Filling Null Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes . One dataframe has a column - 'CUSIP' that has a lot of Null Values. where the columns look like this

```
|Date |Ticker  |RP_ID   |CUSIP |SEDOL |<br/>
```

Another dataframe has two columns 'Ticker ' And 'CUSIP' that looks like this 
 |Ticker  |CUSIP|
I need to fill the fill the CUSIP column in the first column by matching it with the corresponding 'Ticker' in the second dataframe as given below . So far I have done this . Is there a better way to do this. I have around 100000 rows .

```
for key in null_list:
if test_df1.loc[key]['Ticker'] in mapping:
     test_df1.loc[key,'CUSIP'] = mapping.get(test_df1.loc[key]['Ticker'])
```

Where null_list contains the indices of the first dataframe that has null values in the CUSIP index and mapping is a map of values of the second dataframe with 'TICKER' as key and 'CUSIP' as value.
 I am unable to post images as I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: and what seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> pandas.merge(a,b, how='left', on='Ticker', suffixes=('_', '')).drop(['CUSIP_'], axis=1)
```

where

```
a = pandas.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'CUSIP':[None, None, None, None]})
b = pandas.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'CUSIP':['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4']})
```